# Accessing nested list of dictionary with inner list

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to get an expected output: Orea has a salary of 2344

but I had issues accessing the second dictionary 'sales'.

```
Department_Employee_data= [{'Purchase': ['John', 'Avery', 'Obama'], 'Sales': ['Orea', 'Stark']},
                       {'Purchase': [2000, 4000, 10000], 'Sales': [2344, 32442]}]    

for data in Department_Employee_data:
    if data['Sales'][0] == 'Orea':
        print(data['Sales'][0], " has a salary of ", data[[1]['Sales']])
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Department_Employee_data` is a `list` which holds your dictionaries. Since you're already iterating over it, `data` holds only the current result of that iteration - the first (second, third...) dictionary in your list so you cannot access the values of the *next* dictionary in your list through it.

If you want to iterate over the values of the `Sales` key within the first dictionary and then access the values of same indices in the next dictionary you'll have to use `enumerate` to get the matching indexes, e.g.:

```
for index, data in enumerate(Department_Employee_data[0]["Sales"]):
    if data == "Orea":
        print("Orea has a salary of {}".format(Department_Employee_data[1]["Sales"][index]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that your list will always have the employees in first position and salaries in second position

```
employees,salaries=Department_Employee_data;

for department in employees:
    for employee,salary in zip(employees[department],salaries[department]):
        # do whatever you want with the employee, salary and department value
        print("{} of department {} has a salary of {}".format(employee,department,salary))
```